# Why the cells turn blank when they lose the focus in the GridView?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, visual-studio-2015, devexpress, gridcontrol

When I fill a cell, no matter the type of, this turns empty when it lose the focus.

At the same time I cant add a new row (with tab or enter) in a GridView (I got the AllowAddRows=True and the NewItemRowPosition = Bottom properties).
I hope you can help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Could you improve your question some (showing code for example)

Comment: @mnwsmit well, actually Im not using code for the GridControl/GridView yet. I just want to edit a cell inplace without turn it blank when it lose the focus, using the properties. By the way, I guess thats the reason why the Grid neither add new rows.

Comment: Typically a cell will become blank when the cell/row loses focus if you neglect to bind the column by setting the GridColumn.FieldName property to a property/field within the GridControl's DataSource.